# Why is the memory below 0x00400000 in MIPS reserved?

Tags: kernel, mips, cpu-architecture

According to "See Mips Run 2nd edition", the MIPS32 memory layout looks like this:

[image: MIPS32 memory layout.]

From what I understand, kuseg is the memory a process in userspace will end up with. This memory region goes from 0x0000.0000 to 0x7FFF.FFF.

My other book (Patterson and Hennessy), however, has the following picture:

[image: Memory layout from Patterson and Hennessy]

which confused me as to why 0x0040.0000 is reserved for the kernel.

Will also there be some kernel code in kuseg? I'm quite confused, any pointers would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Like Erik tried to say, the diagram shows a reserved part only up to 0x40'0000, the low 4 MiB.  Not the 0x400'0000 (64MiB) you wrote in the title.  IDK why it would reserve that much, but it might be like [Linux's `mmap_min_addr`](https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr), to guard against null-pointer dereference by user-space.  Your 2nd diagram is showing the low half of virtual address space, so that's user-space not kernel.

Comment: Thanks Erik for noticing the mistake, I've edited the question. Regarding @peter-cordes, I understand my second diagram is the user-space and not the kernel, so the second diagram is "equivalent" to the kuseg portion in the first diagram, minus the 0x0040.0000 reserved space, hence my question.

Comment: Ok, I see, fair question then.  But it doesn't say it's reserved ***for** (use by) the kernel*, just that it *is* reserved.  Probably not for anyone's use, like I suggested.  And BTW, your title still has the 64MiB number, with one too many zeros.

Comment: Oops, thanks! Fixed that as well. In the context of the book (and looking at other sources like http://www.it.uu.se/education/course/homepage/os/vt18/module-0/mips-and-mars/mips-memory-layout/) "reserved" is pretty much "reserved for kernel use".

Comment: It is not 0x4000,0000, it's just 0x400,000.

Comment: Like Peter says, it is normal to reserve a range of memory starting at 0 to prevent most null pointer dereferences.  Some systems I've used have reserved as little as 4kB, while others more.  Over the years, there's been a debate as to whether to make this reserved memory read as zeros yet fault for writing or fault for both read and write.  A reason to allow reading to return zeros rather than fault is for compatibility with ""working"" programs that have bugs yet are expected to run on new systems as they did on older systems!